# Google DOC - Multiple FIlters combined

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I'm a newbie when it comes to Google Doc Filters and I would appreciate some help.

I got a list with articles where I would like to filter by company (in this case SONY), but also filtering by lowest price combined with lowest shipping costs.

Example: the first filter I created, creates a list with SONY articles.

```
=(filter(A2:D12;A2:A12="SONY"))
```

Now I would like the filter to give out a single row, where the price and the shipping costs are the lowest, in this case, the product is:

**SONY headphones   with the price of 20 and shipping costs of 2,99**

Im basically trying to combine the filters:

```
=(filter(A2:D12;A2:A12="SONY"))
=SMALL((C2:C12);2)
=SMALL((D2:D12);2)
```

in one single, long filter

Thank you

[SEE SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYSPd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

`FILTER` would not work in your case because you have a priority column to be filtered, in this case, column A before C and D.

You may use `QUERY` instead:

`=QUERY(A2:D12,"select * where A='A' order by C+D limit 1")`

This would select the entry with a specified value in column A (company), then order by the sum of C and D (price+shipping) in ascending order, and then output the first row, which is the minimum.

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

**References:**

[QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

[QUERY language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Comment: Amazing! Can you please tell me how to change the formula if I want a new row with the product by SONY with the second lowest price?

Comment: It's a little more complicated, but you can use ````=QUERY(A2:D12,"select * where A='SONY' and C="&SMALL(UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(A1:D12,A1:A12="SONY"),0,3)),2)&"")````

Comment: Sorry, I meant "second lowest price combined with second lowest shipping costs", basically second lowest cimbination of price and shipping costs, just like u used in the first reply. I tried C+D ="&SMALL(UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(A1:D12,A1:A12="SONY"),0,3)),2)&"") but it didnt work.

Comment: It's simpler, just add ````OFFSET 1```` to the query in my answer. That will get the 2nd item in C+D order.